# Keras R Value Error: No data provided for "dense_59"

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am working with the KERAS package in R for the first time. Using this tutorial as help to guide my first model (https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/tutorial_basic_regression.html). Everything was going smoothly until I got to the actual "building of the model" I was able to replicate the example in the link perfectly, but once I substituted my own data, I could not get this error message to go away
 "**Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: No data provided for "dense_59". Need data for each key in: ['dense_59']** "

I tried adjusting the units and all it did was change the number after "dense_." For what its worth, my training data is 6 columns 964 rows.

```
build_model <- function() {

  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
    layer_dense(units = 5, activation = "relu",
                input_shape = dim(train)[2]) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 5, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1)

  model %>% compile(
    loss = "mse",
    optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
    metrics = list("mean_absolute_error")
  )

  model
}

model <- build_model()
model %>% summary()

print_dot_callback <- callback_lambda(
  on_epoch_end = function(epoch, logs) {
    if (epoch %% 80 == 0) cat("\n")
    cat(".")
  }
)    

epochs <- 200

history <- model %>% fit(
  train,
  train_labels,
  epochs = epochs,
  validation_split = 0.2,
  verbose = 0,
  callbacks = list(print_dot_callback)
)
```

Since this is my first time working with Keras, I really have no idea where to even start when it comes to solving this problem. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not a minimal working example.
your `train` refers to sth not given. Nobody can try your code.
Thus nobody helped.

Always post a minimal working example - although you don't see it often. This is the fastest way to get quickly answers!

However, I took some time to answer this. And created what I needed to have.

**Install `keras` and `R` in a virtual environment**

I use conda, creating virtual environments - because it saves tons of work when you have to install complicated packages like `keras`.

```
# create new environment in conda
conda create --name newR
# enter new environment
conda activate newR
# install 'keras' package - and at the same time R and 
# everything you need to run keras properly.
conda install -c r r-keras

# enter R
R

# to fully intall 'keras' with 'tensorflow', do
require(keras)
install_keras()

# so easy the installation is with conda ... 5 min maybe.
```

**Generate data**

Since you gave no example data, I took iris data.

```
data(iris)
X <- iris[, 1:4]
y <- as.numeric(iris[, 5])
```

The data you gave wants to do regression, but iris' labels `y`
are categorical data. I applied `as.numeric()` on the categorical data to make them numeric.

**Try your given code**

Then, I took your code, changed `train` to `X` and `train_labels` as `y`.

```
build_model <- function() {

  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
    layer_dense(units = 5, activation = "relu",
                input_shape = dim(X)[2]) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 5, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1)

  model %>% compile(
    loss = "mse",
    optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
    metrics = list("mean_absolute_error")
  )

  model
}

print_dot_callback <- callback_lambda(
  on_epoch_end = function(epoch, logs) {
    if (epoch %% 80 == 0) cat("\n")
    cat(".")
  }
)    

epochs <- 200

history <- model %>% fit(
  as.matrix(X),
  y,
  epochs = epochs,
  validation_split = 0.2,
  verbose = 0,
  callbacks = list(print_dot_callback)
)
```

It runs smoothly without any error! (Dots).

```
>history
Trained on 120 samples (batch_size=32, epochs=200)
Final epoch (plot to see history):
                   loss: 0.04127
    mean_absolute_error: 0.1497
               val_loss: 0.1147
val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2761 

# save model
keras::save_model_hdf5(model, filepath = "test_rkeras.h5")

# load model
keras::load_model_hdf5("test_rkeras.h5")
```

which results in:

```
Model
________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                        Output Shape                    Param #     
================================================================================
dense (Dense)                       (None, 5)                       25          
________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                     (None, 5)                       30          
________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                     (None, 1)                       6           
================================================================================
Total params: 61
Trainable params: 61
Non-trainable params: 0
________________________________________________________________________________
```

So it works well!

**Conclusion**

This proves that your model and the code is valid.

Simply your input data must be the problem!
check its structure by using `str(train)`. It should be a simple numeric matrix of 2 dimensions! Is your labels/targets vector a simple numeric vector?

Mostly errors occur when reading-in data.
Always check after reading-in some data that the data looks like you expect it to be!